# Bootstrap Datepicker Disable Selected Days of Month

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do I disable 29/30/31 days of every month using the Bootstrap Datepicker?

Here is my script so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var now = new Date();
            now.setDate(now.getDate());
            $('.firstPaymentDate').datepicker({
                startDate: new Date(),
                beforeShowDay:  function (date) {
                    getDate() //returns the day (0-31)
                    if (date.getDate() == 29 || date.getDate() == 30 || date.getDate() == 31) {
                        return [false, '', 'Unavaliable'];
                    }
                    return [true, ''];
                },
                format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
                todayHighlight: true,

            }).datepicker('setDate', now).attr("readonly", "readonly");
</script>
```

Comment: Is it working? Is it not working? What else have you tried?

Comment: @ElliotM No its not working, I think either the beforeShowDay option could be wrongly coded or I am using an incorrect/older datepicker js file. I am not sure what else to try.

Comment: Do you have errors in your console? What is the behavior of your incorrect implementation? - It looks like you may have a syntax error as well.

Comment: @ElliotM No errors in the console using Chrome, and the days 29/30/31 can be selected which is what I am trying to prevent from happening

Comment: @ElliotM Where do you think the syntax error might be?

Answer (score 0):

I commented the `startDate` line and `getDate()` inside the `beforeShowDay` block and its working. By default the current date is selected as `startDate`.

Check this working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arul4/hru9bfL5/1/

```
$('#firstPaymentDate').datepicker({
    //startDate: new Date(),
    beforeShowDay:  function (date) {
        //getDate(); //returns the day (0-31)
        if (date.getDate() == 29 || date.getDate() == 30 || date.getDate() == 31) 
        {
            return [false, '', 'Unavaliable'];
        }
        return [true, ''];
    },
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    todayHighlight: true
}).datepicker('setDate', now).attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

Comment: this works fine with the JQuery Datepicker but not when using it with Bootstrap, it does not disable the days.